# Fancybox: just some images displayed in page but have more in the gallery

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox, fancybox-2

This is my script that calls FancyBox:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 jQuery(".fancybox").fancybox({
  helpers : { 
   title : { type : 'float' }
  },
      beforeShow: function(){
       this.title = '<div>'+jQuery(this.element).next('div').html()+'</div>';
      }
 });
});
</script>
```

And these are my 6 images in HTML

```
<div id="mydiv">
<a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="IMAGE_URL"><img id="thumb1" src="THUMB_URL" /></a><div style="display: none;">DESCRIPTION</div>
<a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="IMAGE_URL"><img id="thumb2" src="THUMB_URL" /></a><div style="display: none;">DESCRIPTION</div>
<a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="IMAGE_URL"><img id="thumb3" src="THUMB_URL" /></a><div style="display: none;">DESCRIPTION</div>
<a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="IMAGE_URL"><img id="thumb4" src="THUMB_URL" /></a><div style="display: none;">DESCRIPTION</div>
<a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="IMAGE_URL"><img id="thumb5" src="THUMB_URL" /></a><div style="display: none;">DESCRIPTION</div>
<a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="IMAGE_URL"><img id="thumb6" src="THUMB_URL" /></a><div style="display: none;">DESCRIPTION</div>
</div>
```

What I'd like to do is: have only these 6 images displayed in the page but when the user clicks on the next icon (within fancybox), other images are loaded in the gallery (so, arrived at fifth image it won't restart but go on with other images). I can't do this with `display:none` removed when clicking next, because they would be a lot of images. And images with `display:none` are still loaded at load time.
Can you provide me examples of how to do this in a clean way? :)

Comment: The 6 belongs to the same gallery.

Comment: so, does it work? I think there is nothing cleaner like that ;)

Comment: I'll be at home in 1 hour. Will let you know soon :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your extra images, just place their links inside an extra hidden `div` like :

```
<div style="display: none;">
 <a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="IMAGE_URL"></a><div>DESCRIPTION</div>
 <a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="IMAGE_URL"></a><div>DESCRIPTION</div>
 <a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="IMAGE_URL"></a><div>DESCRIPTION</div>
 <a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" href="IMAGE_URL"></a><div>DESCRIPTION</div>
 ... etc
</div>
```

**NOTICE** that the links inside the hidden `div` **HAVE NOT** thumbnail images (`<img />`) so you are not actually adding any overhead to your page load .... and regarding the links, if you want more images in your gallery, you have to hard-code them here or anywhere like inside your script for instance.

Comment: It works! :D I tried to manually add some <a> with that formatting in a hidden div and the images appeared in the gallery. Thanks! :)
If possible, can I ask you another big favour? This is the function I use to pull the first 6 images from Instagram API: http://pastebin.com/L39XL3NJ How could I rewrite it in order to: pull 20 images (count=20), use the same original formatting for the first 6, then use this extra hidden div for all the others? I tried with if($i==6) echo 'BLAHBLAH' but I made something wrong probably. :P

Comment: @MultiformeIngegno : that is another story. Why you don't open a new question using php and html tags (no fancybox tag needed) : ask specifically how to run your php code to generate 6 visible links with thumbnails and the rest inside a hidden `div` with no thumbnails `<img />` tags (and you could accept this answer and close this case ;)