# Fancybox list of pictures not showing up in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, fancybox

I am currently using fancybox for my image gallery. I am having serious difficulty with getting it to work well in Internet Explorer. Every other browser I have tried works - besides Internet Explorer.

**The Problem:**

Every time I reload the page, *some* of the pictures show, and others do not. It's always a random few pictures, not the same ones repeatedly.

I tried the solution posted from [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16999836/fancybox-just-some-images-displayed-in-page-but-have-more-in-the-gallery), but it didn't fix my issue.

This is the code I'm using - is anything in particular sticking out?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul.imagegallery img').resizecrop({
      width: 146,
      height: 146,
      vertical:"top"
    });  
    $('a[href$='.jpg'],a[href$='.png'],a[href$='.gif']').attr('rel', 'gallery');
    $('.fancybox').fancybox({
        beforeLoad: function() {
            this.title = $(this.element).attr('caption');
        },
    prevEffect  : 'none',
    nextEffect  : 'none',
    helpers  : {
      title  : {
        type: 'inside'
      }
    },
        margin : [20, 80, 20, 80]
    });
  }); 
</script>
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jch053/pe8nnase/) if you want to see the page. It looks fine on the fiddle, but it does not work in Internet Explorer.

Comment: you have a stray `$(".fancybox")` selector. Also, your fancybox script should be inside the `.ready()` method

Comment: Hey @JFK I tried to rearrange my code to put my fancybox script inside the `.ready()`. Now all of the pictures seem to be showing up, but when I click them, they just open the image regularly, and not in fancybox format. I have updated my question to my new code.

Comment: works fine on IE11, waht version you trying?

Comment: @JFK IE9 - It's the default for the entire college campus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of looking at this, I believe I have deciphered the answer.

`$('a[href$='.jpg'],a[href$='.png'],a[href$='.gif']').attr('rel', 'gallery');` This line is completely unnecessary.

```
$('ul.imagegallery img').resizecrop({
  width: 146,
  height: 146,
  vertical:"top"
});
```

This is best to just be left out, and supplemented with css by saying:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .imagegallery img {
        width: 146px;
        height: 146px;
     }
</style>
```

From that, the document ready should look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.fancybox").fancybox({
        beforeLoad: function() {
            this.title = $(this.element).attr('caption');
        },
    prevEffect  : 'none',
    nextEffect  : 'none',
    helpers  : {
    title  : {
        type: 'inside'
    }
    },
        margin : [20, 80, 20, 80]
    });
  });
```